# IOS system library cause memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, uikit

I'm in the last stage of my app bugfix and optimizing. I'm debugging leak in an app. There is now only system library that causes the leak `UIKitCore`. Is there anything that we can do?

[image]

[image]

That strange `uikeyboardpredictionview` cause the leak which suspect to be in `main` function

My `main` function is quite traight forward

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var service: MovieService!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let service = MovieService(provider: TMDBprovider)

        let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

        let popularMovieNavi = tabBarController.viewControllers?.first as! UINavigationController
        let popularMovieVC = popularMovieNavi.viewControllers.first as! PopularMovieVC
        popularMovieVC.viewModel = PopularMovieViewModel(service: service)

        let searchMovieNavi = tabBarController.viewControllers?.last as! UINavigationController
        let searchMovieVC = searchMovieNavi.viewControllers.first as! SearchMovieVC
        searchMovieVC.viewModel = SearchMovieViewModel(service: service)

        return true
    }
```

Is that bug can b resolved?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't lose any sleep over a mere few _bytes_ of leak. Gigabytes, yes. Bytes, no.

Comment: That make sense. I Just want to know where the leak come from. Is it because of my code

Comment: I have a similar error with 6 leaks: 5 in QuartzCore (CALayer issues) and 1 in UIKeyboardPredictionView like you do it it causes when I call `becomeFirstResponder()` which shows the keyboard. Do your viewControllers (popularMovie and searchMovie) have a textfield that triggers the keyboard to show up? If yes maybe share some of that code.

Comment: hi @agirault. Thanks for response. I did not have any call to becomeFirstResponder(). but i have my dependency on 'RxKeyboard' (to manage keyboard keyboard doging logic when search text field shows). Did you get rid of the leak?

Comment: And i have this call self?.searchBar.resignFirstResponder() on searchMovie

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I'm currently having the same situation. I'm using IQKeyboardManager as a dependency

Comment: Hey guys, I have pretty much same situation. I'm presenting VC2 from VC1, in VC2 I have a `UITextField` and I want the keyboard to show up directly so I put textfield `becomeFirstResponse()` in `viewDidLoad()`. I think that cause the memory leak because if I removed `becomeFirstResponse()`, no memory leak detected from the graph. Any reason why that happens?